# Accessing jarclassloader method: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, applet

Here's the error I'm getting when I'm trying to call a function in an applet loaded via jarclassloader functions (the first line is output by the function, as seen near the bottom of the code below).

```
MyAppletLauncher:setdestination! Getting webcamclass ...
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
```

The applet loads and functions fine. The routine `setImageDestination()` near the bottom of the code below is where it is dieing.  I call the function `setImageDestination()` from javascript from a button click (for testing). I'm thinking I'm misusing the variable jcl from `initApplet("webcam",this)` in the code below:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class MyAppletLauncher extends JApplet {

    private JarClassLoader jcl;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        jcl = new JarClassLoader();
        try {
            jcl.initApplet("webcam", this);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        jcl.startApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        jcl.stopApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        jcl.destroyApplet();
    }


    public void setImageDestination(String url, int type, int p1, int p2)
     {
       try {
        System.out.println("MyAppletLauncher:setdestination! Getting webcamclass ...");  
        Class webcamclass=jcl.loadClass("webcam");
        System.out.println("   Have webcamclass ... getting method ...");    
        Method m=webcamclass.getMethod("WebcamImageDestination",String[].class);
        System.out.println("   Have method ... invoking ...");   
        m.invoke(jcl,url,type,p1,p2);
        System.out.println("   Invoked.");   
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }    
     } 

} // class MyAppletLauncher
```

Comment: why are you using reflection to access the webcam class?

Comment: I'm using existing code that I've modified.  I need a way to pass information to the java applet so it can post the image to the proper database record. Essentially, I'll open the a browser window with the applet and pass a transaction ID and a URL to post the image to.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a manifest entry to the JAR:

caller-allowable-codebase: *